# How can I prevent an user to change the pc time and modify the timestramp of inserted row in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

It's like this... when i insert a data in the mysql database the datetime used is from the same pc that is running the system. 
The user can easily modify their date or time and insert the data in another day... 
Someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Insert using the database time, like `NOW()` or [`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp). Don't let the originating machine do that itself.

If you can't trust your users to not manipulate their local time **you should not trust them to have access to your database** and should have some kind of API in the middle to prevent tampering.

Anyone with direct write access to your database can probably cause a whole ton of problems beyond faking out dates.

Comment: I'm using sequelize, does sequelize already makes this for me in the createdAt and updatedAt ?

Comment: It depends where Sequelize is running. If it's on some kind of server you control and can limit access to, then sure. If it's on a client machine, nope, you're at the mercy of the user.

Comment: But from where the machine will take the right time ? and if the pc don't have any connection ?

Comment: Yes, i'm running in the same machine

Comment: If you can't trust the machine this code is running on, you can't trust the output. You may need to introduce a secondary server somewhere (e.g. cloud hosted or otherwise) to provide some separation.

Comment: Why not use moment js to create current UTC time and then use this variable for createdAt and updatedAt? Why even be dependent on client machine time? Also, you might want to careful with DateTime fields on Sequelize, in my case, it was returning double the UTC time difference on find queries.

Comment: @RohitDalal Moment.js uses the client machine's time.

Comment: I'm using moment.js to compare some dates, but it still uses the server data, and is easy to modify.

Comment: What I meant was to use the server time. Sequelize code must be running on a backend, not on the client machine(Browser page). If Sequelize code is on the browser than its no longer safe and anyone can see the credentials used for connection to DB. The client cannot modify the server time they can only change their local machine time. On the server side, the time must be UTC and the moment js will work perfectly. Unless I do not understand your scenario. Please do tell.